# Calling stored procedure for each row doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core

I'm having issues while executing stored procedure in a foreach loop, here is my code:

```
 var members = await _context.Members
                .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
                
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=ProductsDb;User=user;Password=password"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CalculateRolesForEachMember", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // open connection ProductsDb database
        con.Open();

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@memberId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = member.Id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)month;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)year;


            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // ON SECOND ITERATION OF FOREACH CODE BREAKS HERE

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                member.MemberType = memberTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Acronym == reader["Role"].ToString());
                member.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here is my exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)

How can I solve/fix this by using this code without introducing data tables?

Comment: Maybe you should add `reader.Close()` in your code...

Comment: Why do you have both an `ExecuteNonQuery()` as well as a `ExecuteReader()` ?? This just basically executes each stored procedure **twice** - once without expecting a result set back (OK for an `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`) and the second time with getting back a result set ...... that's pretty useless.....

Comment: @marc_s it just left after I been experimenting, also even if i Remove cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); I still receive same error..

Comment: @marc_s  Check for my update mate it still breaks even if I removed unused code and I applied some code from the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to dispose your reader with a `using` block.** Don't be tempted to do it yourself with `.Close()`, it's not worth it:

```cs
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    member.MemberType = memberTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Acronym == reader["Role"].ToString());
                    member.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call cmd.Parameters.Clear(); after each command execution

```
     .....

foreach (var member in members)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@memberId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = member.Id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)month;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)year;

    //  What do you need this for ????
    // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            member.MemberType = memberTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Acronym == reader["Role"].ToString());
            member.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

            _context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
}
```

another way is to reuse parameters instead of calling clear();

```
.....

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@memberId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value =Guid.Empty;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)month;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)year;

foreach (var member in members)
        {
            
cmd.Parameters["@memberId"].Value =  member.Id;

.....

}
```

And by the way what do you need   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); for?

Comment: Or **define** the parameters **once**, before the loop - and then only **set their values** inside the loop, to avoid having to define the same parameters over and over again ....

Comment: @Sergey I've been experimenting different variations while trying to solve this, but even if I remove cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); I still have same issue.. hmm

Comment: Did you remove CommandBehavior.CloseConnection?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro You are right. I fixed my code. Try again pls.

Answer (score 0):

If my way of thinking is correct, You need to change one thing. Currently You declare cmd before the foreach loop, so for each member You are changing existing command.
I think that You should go from this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CalculateRolesForEachMember", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // open connection ProductsDb database
    con.Open();

    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@memberId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = member.Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)month;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)year;

        // IN SECOND ITERATION CODE BREAKS HERE
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            member.MemberType = memberTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Acronym == reader["Role"].ToString());
            member.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

To this:

```
       foreach (var member in members)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CalculateRolesForEachMember", con))
            {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // open connection ProductsDb database
        con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@memberId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = member.Id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)month;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)year;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                member.MemberType = memberTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Acronym == reader["Role"].ToString());
                member.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
}
```

There is better solution in terms of performance, that's for sure, but it will do it's job.